# Parsing Complex JSON Objects with inheritance

Tags: json, typescript, local-storage

I'm building a batch process that includes a number of steps of varying types.

```
export interface IStep {
    id: number;
    icon: string;
    name: string;
    selected: boolean;
}

export class InitStep implements IStep {
    id: number;
    icon: string;
    name: string;
    selected = false;
}

export class InputStep implements IStep {
    id: number;
    icon: string;
    name: string;
    selected = false;
    primaryKey: string;
    file: File;
}

export class QueryStep implements IStep {
    constructor () {
        this.filters = [];
        this.output_fields = [];
        this.table_fields = [];
        const filter = new Filter;
        this.filters.push(filter);
    }

    get input_ids(): number[] {
        return this.filters.map(filter => filter.input_id);
    }

    id: number;
    icon: string;
    name: string;
    selected = false;
    table: string;
    table_fields: string[];
    filters: Filter[];
    output_fields: string[];
}

export class OutputStep implements IStep {

    constructor() {
        this.fields = [];
    }

    id: number;
    icon: string;
    name: string;
    selected = false;
    fields: string[];
}

export class DeliveryStep implements IStep {

    constructor() {
        this.output_ids = [];
    }

    id: number;
    icon: string;
    name: string;
    selected = false;
    output_ids: number[];
    format: BatchOutputType;
    frequency: BatchFrequencyType;
    email: string;
    password: string;
}
```

I want to be able to have an array of any combination/number of these steps and be able to save them to and read from localstorage.

```
const key = 'notgunnawork';
localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(this.steps));
const s = JSON.parse(key) as IStep[];
```

I knew there was a snowball's chance in hell this was going to parse correctly, obviously the parser doesn't know which steps belong to what classes ultimately. I was just wondering if there was a simple way to get my array to come out looking the same way it went in. I'll eventually be posting this list to the server and would like my .Net Core code to also be able to parse this JSON without me having to make a custom parser.

EDIT

Added the full classes of what Im trying to serialize, for more detail. The error I'm getting whenever I try to serialize and then deserialize is: "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"

Comment: I think this will get downvoted unless you provide more details. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't understand why this is not working as you want! Everything should be fine with your code

Comment: I'm trying to read between the lines here... is your problem that the serialized/deserialized items are no longer instances of your classes?  If so, maybe classes are not buying you much and you can get by with just interfaces instead.  Or you will have to make a custom reviver for your JSON parsing to deserialize into class instances.  But I think we need more info before we can help you.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for your comments, I've added the actual classes if that adds any insight and the error Im getting as soon as I try to serialize and then deserialize the JSON.

Comment: Are you parsing the localstorage *key* instead of the -*value*?  That needs to be fixed before you can worry about deserializing into class instances.

Comment: No the key will be just a string that’s static and known. Just worrying about the value

Comment: From your code: `const s = JSON.parse(key) as IStep[];`  you're parsing the `key` for some reason.  Why are you doing that?

Comment: You should try to post a [mcve] so that someone can just run your code and see the problem instead of first trying to deduce what the problem is. My guess is that you'd like your class instances to survive a roundtrip through serialization/deserialization but your example code doesn't show that; a good example would be something like: code that creates some instances of your classes, code that serializes those instances, and then code that tries to deserialize them, and then code that shows that something unexpected has happened. Preferably self-contained code with no external dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I'm going to answer what I *think* your issue is, and if I'm wrong then feel free to ignore me

Your problem is that you have a bunch of classes with methods but when you serialize instances of these to JSON and then deserialize them back, you end up with plain-old JavaScript objects and not instances of your classes.   One way to handle this is to use a custom deserializer which knows about your classes and can "hydrate" or "revive" the plain-old JavaScript objects into genuine class instances.  The `JSON.parse()` function allows you to specify a callback parameter called [`reviver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter) which can be used to do just that.

First, we need to set up a system by which the reviver will know about your serializable classes.  I'm going to use a [class decorator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators) which will add each class constructor to a registry the reviver can use.  We will require that a serializable class constructor be assignable to a type we can call `Serializable`: it needs to have a no-argument constructor and the things it constructs need to have a `className` property:

```
// a Serializable class has a no-arg constructor and an instance property
// named className
type Serializable = new () => { readonly className: string }

// store a registry of Serializable classes
const registry: Record<string, Serializable> = {};

// a decorator that adds classes to the registry
function serializable<T extends Serializable>(constructor: T) {
  registry[(new constructor()).className] = constructor;
  return constructor;
}
```

Now, when you want to deserialize some JSON, you can check if the serialized thing has a `className` property that's a key in the registry.  If so, you use the constructor for that classname in the registry, and copy properties into it via [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
// a custom JSON parser... if the parsed value has a className property
// and is in the registry, create a new instance of the class and copy
// the properties of the value into the new instance.
const reviver = (k: string, v: any) =>
  ((typeof v === "object") && ("className" in v) && (v.className in registry)) ?
    Object.assign(new registry[v.className](), v) : v;

// use this to deserialize JSON instead of plain JSON.parse        
function deserializeJSON(json: string) {
  return JSON.parse(json, reviver);
}
```

Okay now that we have that, let's make some classes.  (I'm using your original definitions here, before your edits.)  Note that we are required to add a `className` property and we must have a no-arg constructor (this happens for free if you don't specify a constructor, since the [default constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor#Description) is no-arg):

```
// mark each class as serializable, which requires a className and a no-arg constructor
@serializable
class StepType1 implements IStep {
  id: number = 0;
  name: string = "";
  prop1: string = "";
  readonly className = "StepType1"
}

@serializable // error, property className is missing
class OopsNoClassName {

}

@serializable // error, no no-arg constructor
class OopsConstructorRequiresArguments {
  readonly className = "OopsConstructorRequiresArguments"
  constructor(arg: any) {

  }
}

@serializable
class StepType2 implements IStep {
  id: number = 0;
  name: string = "";
  prop2: string = "";
  prop3: string = "";
  prop4: string = "";
  readonly className = "StepType2"
}

@serializable
class StepType3 implements IStep {
  id: number = 0;
  name: string = "";
  prop5: string = "";
  prop6: string = "";
  readonly className = "StepType3"
}
```

Now let's test it out.  Make some objects as you would normally do, and put them in an array:

```
// create some objects of our classes
const stepType1 = new StepType1();
stepType1.id = 1;
stepType1.name = "Alice";
stepType1.prop1 = "apples";

const stepType2 = new StepType2();
stepType2.id = 2;
stepType2.name = "Bob";
stepType2.prop2 = "bananas";
stepType2.prop3 = "blueberries";
stepType2.prop4 = "boysenberries";

const stepType3 = new StepType3();
stepType3.id = 3;
stepType3.name = "Carol";
stepType3.prop5 = "cherries";
stepType3.prop6 = "cantaloupes";

// make an array of IStep[]
const arr = [stepType1, stepType2, stepType3];
```

And let's have a function which will examine the elements of an array and check to see if they are instances of your classes:

```
// verify that an array of IStep[] contains class instances
function verifyArray(arr: IStep[]) {
  console.log("Array contents:\n" + arr.map(a => {
    const constructorName = (a instanceof StepType1) ? "StepType1" :
      (a instanceof StepType2) ? "StepType2" :
        (a instanceof StepType3) ? "StepType3" : "???"
    return ("id=" + a.id + ", name=" + a.name + ", instanceof " + constructorName)
  }).join("\n") + "\n");
}
```

Let's make sure it works on `arr`:

```
// before serialization, everything is fine
verifyArray(arr);
// Array contents:
// id=1, name=Alice, instanceof StepType1
// id=2, name=Bob, instanceof StepType2
// id=3, name=Carol, instanceof StepType3
```

Then we serialize it:

```
// serialize to JSON
const json = JSON.stringify(arr);
```

To demonstrate your original problem, let's see what happens if we just use `JSON.parse()` without a reviver:

```
// try to deserialize with just JSON.parse
const badParsedArr = JSON.parse(json) as IStep[];

// uh oh, none of the deserialized objects are actually class instances
verifyArray(badParsedArr);
// Array contents:
// id=1, name=Alice, instanceof ???
// id=2, name=Bob, instanceof ???
// id=3, name=Carol, instanceof ???
```

As you can see, the objects in `badParsedArr` do have the `id` and `name` properties (and the other class-specific instance properties like `prop3` if you checked) but they are not instances of your classes.

Now we can see if the problem is fixed by using our custom deserializer:

```
// do the deserialization with our custom deserializer
const goodParsedArr = deserializeJSON(json) as IStep[];

// now everything is fine again
verifyArray(goodParsedArr);
// Array contents:
// id=1, name=Alice, instanceof StepType1
// id=2, name=Bob, instanceof StepType2
// id=3, name=Carol, instanceof StepType3
```

Yes, it works!

---

The above method is fine, but there are caveats.   The main one: it will work if your serializable classes contain properties which are themselves serializable, as long as your object graph is a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory)), where each object appears *exactly once*.  But if you have an object graph with any kind of [cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory)) in it (meaning that the same object appears multiple times if you traverse the graph multiple ways) then you will get unexpected results.  For example:

```
const badArr = [stepType1, stepType1];
console.log(badArr[0] === badArr[1]); // true, same object twice
const badArrParsed = deserializeJSON(JSON.stringify(badArr));
console.log(badArrParsed[0] === baddArrParsed[1]); // false, two different objects
```

In the above case, the same object appears multiple times.  When you serialize and deserialize the array, your new array contains two *different* objects with the same property values.  If you need to make sure that you only deserialize any particular object exactly once, then you need a more complicated `deserialize()` function which keeps track of some unique property (like `id`) and returns existing objects instead of creating new ones.

Other caveats: this assumes your serializable classes have instance properties consisting only of other serializable classes as well as JSON-friendly values like strings, numbers, arrays, plain objects, and `null`.  If you use other things, like `Date`s, you will have to deal with the fact that those serialize into strings.

Exactly how complicated serialization/deserialization is for you depends heavily on your use case.

---

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Holy crap, yes this exactly! Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey @jcalz, thanks for your detailed answer. I am working on a similar problem as ikenread but I am also having to deal with actual inheritance. Right now I have a main class Event which I derive subclasses from.

How would I go about archiving the same behaviour you described?

Comment: Not sure... You might need to post a new question with a [mcve] and mention what you've tried (and why the code here doesn't work for it).  I don't see what the issue would be, except maybe you should ensure that the `className` property of superclasses is still of type `string` and not narrowed to a string literal?